# How can I trigger a GNURadio flowgraph to load and start running?

Tags: gnuradio-companion

Using Ubuntu. I have a flowgraph that runs in GNURadio which opens a file (containing IQ signal data) and displays it to a QT GUI frequency sink. It works fine when I manually load the grc file into gnuradio-companion and click the green GO arrow. However, I want to trigger this to run from another program (C or Python, whichever works). I can get the flowgraph to load, but I can't get it to run.

It appears to require keyboard input. I have tried sending it commands using named pipes as well as tried it with 4 different keystroke emulators (keyboard, pynput, xdotool, mkfifo), with and without running under sudo (always in a separate terminal window). The GNURadio companion does not react to any of my attempts to send it the keystrokes to run the flowgraph (i.e., using the actual keys, one can use alt-r to bring up the Run menu, the down key to move down to select Run, and the enter key to trigger it to run; and that works).  I have made sure to identify the window when needed (you can do this using the search feature in xdotool, for example; the Python methods seem to require you to manually select the gnuradio-companion window).

What am I missing?  Does GNURadio use some type of linux window that looks for something different than the standard X-terminal input?

The grc file I am trying to use follows.  The file I am trying to display was previously saved by gnuradio-companion (it is IQIQIQ... , 32-bit floating point spectrum).

```
options:
  parameters:
    author: ''
    category: '[GRC Hier Blocks]'
    cmake_opt: ''
    comment: ''
    copyright: ''
    description: ''
    gen_cmake: 'On'
    gen_linking: dynamic
    generate_options: qt_gui
    hier_block_src_path: '.:'
    id: A2
    max_nouts: '0'
    output_language: python
    placement: (0,0)
    qt_qss_theme: ''
    realtime_scheduling: ''
    run: 'True'
    run_command: '{python} -u {filename}'
    run_options: prompt
    sizing_mode: fixed
    thread_safe_setters: ''
    title: showfile
    window_size: ''
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [8, 8]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled

blocks:
- name: samp_rate
  id: variable
  parameters:
    comment: ''
    value: '32000'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [184, 12]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: blocks_file_source_0
  id: blocks_file_source
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    begin_tag: pmt.PMT_NIL
    comment: ''
    file: /home/odroid/projects/signaldata/f3.dat
    length: '0'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    offset: '0'
    repeat: 'True'
    type: float
    vlen: '1024'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [200, 200.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: blocks_throttle_0
  id: blocks_throttle
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    ignoretag: 'True'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    samples_per_second: samp_rate
    type: float
    vlen: '1024'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [440, 204.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: qtgui_vector_sink_f_0
  id: qtgui_vector_sink_f
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    alpha1: '1.0'
    alpha10: '1.0'
    alpha2: '1.0'
    alpha3: '1.0'
    alpha4: '1.0'
    alpha5: '1.0'
    alpha6: '1.0'
    alpha7: '1.0'
    alpha8: '1.0'
    alpha9: '1.0'
    autoscale: 'False'
    average: '1.0'
    color1: '"blue"'
    color10: '"dark blue"'
    color2: '"red"'
    color3: '"green"'
    color4: '"black"'
    color5: '"cyan"'
    color6: '"magenta"'
    color7: '"yellow"'
    color8: '"dark red"'
    color9: '"dark green"'
    comment: ''
    grid: 'False'
    gui_hint: ''
    label1: ''
    label10: ''
    label2: ''
    label3: ''
    label4: ''
    label5: ''
    label6: ''
    label7: ''
    label8: ''
    label9: ''
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    name: '""'
    nconnections: '1'
    ref_level: '0'
    showports: 'False'
    update_time: '0.10'
    vlen: '1024'
    width1: '1'
    width10: '1'
    width2: '1'
    width3: '1'
    width4: '1'
    width5: '1'
    width6: '1'
    width7: '1'
    width8: '1'
    width9: '1'
    x_axis_label: '"x-Axis"'
    x_start: '0'
    x_step: '1.0'
    x_units: '""'
    y_axis_label: '"y-Axis"'
    y_units: '""'
    ymax: '2'
    ymin: '-2'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [800, 132.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true

connections:
- [blocks_file_source_0, '0', blocks_throttle_0, '0']
- [blocks_throttle_0, '0', qtgui_vector_sink_f_0, '0']

metadata:
  file_format: 1
```

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Do you have custom OOT blocks in your flowgraph and can you reproduce the problem without them? Which Ubuntu version do you use, how did you install gnuradio and which version?

Comment: The gnuradio-companion I have installed is 3.8.0.0 ; Python 3.6.9; Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I have no custom OOT blocks. If I remember correctly (this was months ago), I had to build gnuradio from source, as the Ubuntu package would not install using apt. I will add the source of the grc file into the original question...

Comment: Does it work when you start the flowgraph from the terminal `./A2.py`? When I tried it your flowgraph starts as expected and do not require any keyboard input.

Comment: Yes, it does!   - thanks - I was not aware that it could work this way.